# .NET Core and .NET Framework interaction

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We have a project that references multiple NuGet libraries requiring the .NET Framework. If we migrate to .NET Core, can we continue to use those NuGet libraries?

If I want to pass a `Type` object from .NET Core to a NuGet package using the .NET Framework, will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you migrate to .NET Core, all dependencies you use will have to target .NET Core too.

It is possible to reference libraries only for one type of framework, for example

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Akka": "1.0.6"
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {
  }
}
```

and use `#if DNX451` to include them in the code only when targeting the full framework

```
#if DNX451
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Akka.Actor.ActorBase));
#endif
```

It means however that the behavior provided by the library has too be implemented manually for .NET Core.

Comment: @mason OP is asking about references, not #IFDEF, in which .net or msbuild #IFDEF is supported for package references? both answers are valid.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

you will have to migrate your dependencies to dotnet core.

Comment: It doesn't have to. That's why I said optionally. I simply assumed OPs dependencies are net451. I edited the answer now to remove it.